# Basic authentication for Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've tried a few examples online but non of them have worked for my need.

I'm the only person using the project and I want to place a single static username password for all the controllers.

How can I configure Spring boot for a static username/pass using basic http auth?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you trying to build, but have you tried this [link](http://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-rest-basic-authentication),

It simply suggest below snippet, where you have username/password hardcoded, for basic auth.

You can externalize them to property file as well.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("john123").password("password").roles("USER");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put Spring Security on your classpath (I assume you already did that). Spring Boot will enable Basic Auth web security by default, generating a username 'user' and a random password which you can find in the log when starting your application.
2. Put the following in your `application.properties` file:

   - `spring.security.user.name=<your username>`
   - `spring.security.user.password=<your password>`

   This will override the Spring Boot standard behaviour. If you're working with roles, you can also set `spring.security.user.roles` to your liking.

Comment: This works well, however the authentication uses a html form for username/password. Any way to change this to basic http authentication?